# Obj-C Reading CSV File with fscanf or equivalent

Tags: objective-c, c, csv, io, scanf

So I need to read a CSV file with minimal (or reasonably close to minimal) expenditure of memory using Objective-C. Right now I do it approximately like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
NSArray* rowStrings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];
for (NSString* rowString in rowStrings){
    //Analyze row here
    NSArray* cells = [rowString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSMutableArray* row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString* cell in cells){
        //Analyze individual cell here
    }
}
```

But this is not ok because it basically loads the whole file into memory and it goes downhill from there. I believe that I can use fscanf to get the results that I need, but I cannot figure out how this can be done. I could find plenty of examples online of fscanf being used to read files with a known number of "cells" (comma separated values) but I cannot find any examples of what to do when I want to use a file of arbitrary size. I figure that this should be done by separating the file by commas and every time a newline is found simply recognize this and do something about it, which in effect would allow me to read the file cell by cell, but I do not know how to do this with fscanf so if someone could help out that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the usual C stdio in Objective C. That sounds like what you want. fopen(), fgets(), sscanf() etc.

Comment: You can use `NSInputStream` to read the file in small chunks instead of loading the whole file into memory. Depends on what level you want to work with.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: Makes sense, but scanf() also uses the same pattern system as fscanf and I do not know how to get it to read a file of arbitrary size (i.e. with an unknown number of columns) and identify when a line ends.

Comment: Large enough that its a problem and the potential use case has even larger files and I unfortunately do not have a say in that.

Comment: So, you will ultimately need to read in chunks, build at least a minimal data structure to know where you are in the file, and read chunks, analyze the chunks until you find the next delimiter you are looking for. Since CSV files are normally clearly broken into text lines, you might leverage that, unless the lines are also ridiculously long.

Comment: You can use fgetln() for efficient line-by-line input, assuming you are willing to read an entire line at a time.